# Initialize typedef struct by attribute problem

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I defined an struct based on bytes, with size of 3 bytes. (1 packetID and 2 packetSize) I checked the size with sizeof function, and it works well:

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT{
    unsigned char packetID[1];
    unsigned char packetSize[2];
}
```

I created a variable and reserved memory like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT * environment_struct = new ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT();
```

For now I want to initialize *environment_struct*.

The problem is about I am trying to initialize this struct by attribute, just like this:

```
*environment_struct->packetSize = 100;
```

But when I checked this value, using:

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << environment_struct->packetSize << endl;
```

> **Result:** Packet Size: d
>
> **Expected result:** Packet Size: 100

If i will work with numbers, Should I define the struct using csdint library? For example, u_int8 and this type of variable.

Comment: Do you really want to use an array of 1 character, or would it be okay to just use a single character? Similarly, do you want the `packetSize` to be an array of two bytes, or could you use an `unsigned short`?

Comment: I thank to use unsigned char because I had control with bytes size... But with this example I understand that is better to use csdint library to define the struct with u_int8 and uint_16. What do you think?

Comment: I think those would work very well, when you need to control the exact size of your data.

Comment: Perfect, I will redefine the struct with csdint library. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT * environment_struct = new ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT();
```

you initialize `packetSize` to be `{0, 0}`.  Then

```
*environment_struct->packetSize = 100;
```

turns the array into `{100, 0}`.  Since the array is a character array when you send it to `cout` with

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << environment_struct->packetSize << endl;
```

it treats it as a c-string and prints out the string contents.  Since you see `d` that means your system is using ascii as the character `'d'` has an integer representation of `100`.  To see the `100` you need to cast it to an `int` like

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << static_cast<int>(*environment_struct->packetSize) << endl;
```

---

Do note that since `packetSize` is an array of two chars you can't actually assign a single value that takes up that whole space.  If you want this then you need to use fixed width types like

```
typedef struct ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT{
    uint8_t packetID; // unsigned integer that is exactly 8 bits wide.  Will be a compiler error if it does not exist
    uint16_t packetSize; // unsigned integer that is exactly 16 bits wide.  Will be a compiler error if it does not exist
};

int main()
{
    ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT * environment_struct = new ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT();
    environment_struct->packetSize = 100;
    std::cout << "Packet Size: " << environment_struct->packetSize << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you NathanOliver, this is the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider what `*environment_struct->packetSize = 100;` does. It sets the first byte of `ENVIRONMENT_STRUCT::packetSize` to 100. A more conventional syntax to do this is: `environment_struct->packetSize[0] = 100`.

There's really no way to initialize the struct in a way for the expression `std::cout << environment_struct->packetSize` to result in the output of 100. Let us consider what that does. `environment_struct->packetSize` is an array, which in this case decays to a pointer to first element. Character pointers inserted into character streams are interpreted as null terminated character strings. Luckily, you had valueinitialized the second byte of `environment_struct->packetSize`, so your array is indeed null terminated. The value of the first byte is interpreted as an encoded character. On your system encoding, it happens that `d` character is encoded as value 100.

If you wish to print the numeric value of the first byte of `environment_struct->packetSize`, which you had set to 100, you can use:

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << (int)environment_struct->packetSize[0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As packetSize is declared as char-type, it's being output as a character.  (ASCII code of character 'd' is 100...)

Try casting it to an integer-type:

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << (int)environment_struct->packetSize << endl;
```

Alternatively, since you appear to want to store the number as a 2-byte type, you could avoid such casting and simply declare `packetSize` as `unsigned short`.  This will be interpreted by `cout` as an integer-type.

Comment: I declared unsigned char to manage bytes size. So, if i will work with numbers Should I work with u_int or something like that?

Comment: @Ian there is [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) now to represent just a byte of data.

Comment: @JoseJimRin there are [`uint8_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) or `uint_least8_t`

Comment: Yes, for now I understand that i need to use csdint library for this example. Thank you.

Comment: You live and learn!  Mind you, if OP wanted 2 bytes to store the number, we should be talking about `uint16_t`...

Comment: @JoseJimRin note that `std::cout` may still output char instead int.

Comment: @appleapple ok, I understand it now. But I will use csdint library in the future because I used unsigned char by the control of bytes. And it is wrong. Is better to use u_int8 or  u_int16 for this example.

Answer (score 0):

You get this result as you tries to print a character symbol not an integer.

To fix it just cast the value or declare it as integer depending on your needs.

**Cast example:**

```
std::cout << "Packet Size: " << static_cast<int>(*environment_struct->packetSize) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I suggest including some example code that would perform the cast.